# Create a line break in my PHP email form

Tags: php, forms, email

\I hope someone can help. I am a bit of a dunce with php but I managed to create a booking form for my bed and breakfast using a mail.php page called up from the html form.

The body goes like this:

```
$subject = "Booking Request"; 
$fields = array(); 

$fields{"title"} = "Title";
$fields{"name"} = "Name";
$fields{"email"} = "email";
$fields{"telephone"} = "telephone";
$fields{"mobile"} = "mobile";
$fields{"arrival_day"} = "arrival day";
$fields{"departure_day"} = "departure day";
$fields{"adults"} = "#  of adults";
$fields{"children"} = "# of children";
$fields{"questions"} = "any questions?";
```

It works but everything comes out on one line like this

> Title: Ms Name: Joe Blogs email: joe@blogs.com.au telephone: 02 12345697 mobile: 01234958arrival day: 10/06/12 departure day: 20/06/12 # of adults: 8 # of children: 4 any questions?

but I want it to look like this:

> Title: Ms
>   Name: Joe Blogs
>   email: joe@blogs.com.au
>   etc.

I've tried `\n`, `\r` and `<br/>` in all sorts of places but I'm just stabbing in the dark... can what i have be fixed or do I need to use an entirely different code?

Comment: That's not how you do arrays in PHP. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: try using the html `<br>` tag to create a new line.

Comment: `/n` is not a valid line break. It should be `\n`. Or change the email type to text/html and use `<br>`.

Comment: You must use \n for new line .For additional info, it will be better if you set your header for html.
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

Comment: sorry, i did actually do \n and \r - just bad typing when I wrote the question! Where exactly should I put "\n" - I have tried it in a few places but to no effect...

Answer (score 1):

You should use `\n` as an end line.

And please change `{}` to `[]`:

```
$fields["title"] = "Title";
$fields["name"] = "Name";
$fields["email"] = "email";
$fields["telephone"] = "telephone";
...
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip about changing {} to [] , Michal, I have done that. And changed the headers. But as I am a novice I still do not understand exactly where in each line of code to put the \n and how the syntax works. I have tried at the end of each line before the ; - after the ;  after the word "Title" etc - I have tried it every where but it either makes no difference or returns an error. Sorry for being so strupid but I guess I should leave this to the experts!

Comment: @user1351271 put "\n" wherever you want a line break to occur. `$fields['title'] = "Title\n";`

Comment: I have tried that.    $fields["title"] = "Title\n";   
$fields["name"] = "Name\n";   
$fields["email"] = "email\n";  
$fields["telephone"] = "telephone\n";  but it makes no difference. The email comes in with everything on the same line  :(

Comment: Thank you everybody for your help - I solved the problem using <br> in each line like this:  $fields['title'] = "<br>Title"

Answer (score 0):

I used to use "\n":

```
$text = 'line1\n line 2\n line 3';
```

The result were:

```
line1\n
line2\n
line3
```

And i was not satisfied so i found PHP_EOL

```
$text = 'line 1' . PHP_EOL . 'line 2' . PHP_EOL . 'line 3';
```

The result will be:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

`"<br>"` is a viable solution but you're sending "HTML" formatted email.

Answer (score 0):

Use `nl2br();`

```
$message = nl2br($name . " " . " wrote this:" . "\n" . $_POST['message'] . $_POST['phone'] . $_POST['email']  . "\n" . $_POST['radio']);
```